# Resources/explanations for conformal geometry with “null cones at infinity”

Tags: conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation, online-resources, compactification

In the Wikipedia article on conformal geometry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry there’s a section in Mobius geometry that says it’s the study of pseudo Euclidean spaces with either a point or a null cone added to infinity.

Is there a resource for this Minkowski version with the null cones at infinity? All the ones I’ve seen cost $40.

Comment: Maybe this: https://qnlw.info/post/conformal-compactification-spacetime2/