# Mechanics of Clifford Algebra valued Möbius Maps

Tags: mobius-transformation, online-resources, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

The Möbius maps

$$ (ax+b)(cx+d)^{-1} $$

Where $a,b,c,d,x \in \mathbb{C}$ are well-understood, but how do the ones where the variable and coefficients are in Clifford Algebras act?

Are there any good resources for further reading on this?

Comment: Besides the usual $\{\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H\}$, Clifford algebras (over $\Bbb R$) have zero divisors. It's considered acceptable if $0$ isn't invertible because we can extend the action to a projective line where $1/0=\infty$, but how do you propose to fix this problem if $0$ isn't the only noninvertible element?

Comment: @runway44 that’s what https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402662/resources-explanations-for-conformal-geometry-with-null-cones-at-infinity?noredirect=1#comment9213149_4402662 is for